# Spoofing mysql-client connection request for demo purposes

Tags: mysql, spoofing

For demo purpose, I wanted to start at least 5 MySQL-client connection to only one server. Mysql-server is running on a fixed IP.
In my script, I have added many IP's as following.

```
eth0     inet addr:1.2.3.4    
eth0:1  inet addr:1.2.3.5
```

I am the mysql client request as follows:

```
mysql -u test -h mysql.domain.com -p
```

This request always goes with 1.2.3.4?  Can I start the mysql-client request with the IP I wanted?

Comment: It will use your default gateway. You would need to add a route to go out of the second IP for the IP address of the server. Something like `route add -host 5.4.5.5 gw 1.2.3.5` There isn't a mysql flag to use a specific adapter.

Comment: I am writting a script in that will make multiple sql client connection to one remote sql server . In place of using multiple VM(2 or 3)) I am trying to use one VM with multiple IP. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it can be defined in the mysql client.
However good'ol networking should be your friend here.

The idea here is to make sure that IP traffic from your machine to the server machine goes through the desired NIC as its gateway.
The command on *nix is 'route add' and the syntax should be something in the spirit of:
`route add -host <YOUR DB SERVER IP> gw 1.2.3.5 dev <YOUR NIC DEVICE NAME>`

Comment: I am writting a script in that will make multiple sql client connection to one remote sql server . In place of using multiple VM(2 or 3)) I am trying to use one VM with multiple IP. Any help?

Comment: If the connections need to be simultaneous, then I can't think of a way to do it from one VM, unless the MySQL server also has multiple IP addresses that you could add routes for. You could write a script that makes a series of connections from different IP addresses by adding and removing the routes in your script.

Comment: Froyke, I am giving your answer an upvote because you have cahoonas

Comment: Good idea, I can add multiple IP of server and make multiple connection from client,

Comment: @varlogtim - lol, I didn't see your comment but thanks anyway ;) see you around...